# How to define access condition based on @PathVariable or @RequestBody in Keycloak?

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

We are using Keycloak v6.0.0 and Spring Framework. We want to define some access conditions based on `@PathVariable` value and `@RequestBody` fields value in Keycloak admin panel, but we can't find any way to do this. How can we access these fields value and define Resource or Policy based on it?

Comment: Did you solve the problem using my response?

Comment: @DinaBogdan unfortunately, no. I think there is no way to do this. Keycloak admin panel and it's Spring Boot library don't have required infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it will help you the [Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html). Also, I've write a [Keycloak-Client](https://github.com/dinabogdan/keycloak-client) in Kotlin for some basic APIs like: signUp, login and logout. Maybe it will help you.